# Vue Named Slots Caveat?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When using Named Slots with Vue (utilizing the older, more verbose API for component slots), if I have a reusable component defined with a template like this:

```
<template>
 <div v-for="field in formFields">
  <slot name="`${field.key}_PREPEND`">
   <span hidden></span>
  </slot>
  <slot name="`${field.key}_FIELD`">
    <slot name="`${field.key}_LABEL`">{{ field.label }}</slot>
    <slot name="`${field.key}_CONTROL`">
      <input v-if="field.type === 'text'" v-model="model[field.key]"></input>
      <input type="checkbox" v-else-if="field.type === 'checkbox'" v-model="model[field.key]"></input>
    </slot>
  </slot>
  <slot name="`${field.key}_APPEND`">
   <span hidden></span>
  </slot>
 </div>
</template>
```

(this is essentially a hollowed out version of an auto-form generating component I have)

I can then reuse this component like so:

```
<auto-form
   :fields="someArray"
   :model="someObject"
>
   <template slot="Name_PREPEND"> This goes before the name field </template>
   <template slot="Name_FIELD"> For some reason this isn't being rendered, the default slot markup is</template>
   <template slot="Name_APPEND"> This goes after the name field </template>
</auto-form>
```

For some reason, using the above markup (`<auto-form>`), the slot "`${field.key}_FIELD`" is ignored.

If I change the inner markup of the _PREPEND field like so

```
<slot name="`${field.key}_PREPEND`">
   <span hidden>
     <slot name="`${field.key}_CONTENT`"></slot>
   </span>
 </slot>
```

I similarly cannot override the _PREPEND slot (but can override _CONTENT)

Is this simply a limitation of Vue component slots? i.e. Are nested component slots not allowed?

In this particular case, the limitation would prevent a developer using this AutoForm component from say, overriding both the control and label at once via the _FIELD slot (for my uses I wanted to add logic that made a particular field conditional based on the value of other fields in the form)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, it's a bit of a sneaky one.

It looks like if you do conditional rendering on markup that is supposed to override a slot, the default slot will render in its place when it is not conditionally rendered.

So, the simple solution is to use `v-show` instead of `v-if` when you try to override the component slot.

(Has nothing to do with nested component slots as originally suspected)